# getElementById fails on cloned object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, clone

I am using boostrap carousel. I defined a class named `multi-item-carousel`. The js code is as follows,

```
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone(true,true).appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone(true,true).appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone(true,true).appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

I choose `clone(true,true)` because the the children of `item` have event to listen. The code is as follows,

```
  $(".img_change_c").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
   // alert("click bound to document listening for #test-element");
    var imgH = document.getElementById('img_change').offsetHeight;
     alert(imgH);
      jQuery(this).find('img').stop().animate({
        top: imgH-2*imgH+"px"
     }, {
       queue: false,
       duration: 200
     });
});
```

On the cloned objects, the events are triggered. But `getElementById('img_change')` is fail. Since I use `clone(true,true)`,it should copy every. So why did it fail?

Comment: add html. Because now is not possible to help you. What is img_change id?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique throughout the whole document. you clone the node and violate that rule. The browser is not equipped to deal with that. How do you get the second index/occurance of a single item? It's not even a list of length 1, it's just that one node.